# Array returned not equal to the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve this question on LeetCode:

> Given two sorted integer arrays nums1 and nums2, merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array.
>
> Note: The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively.
>
> You may assume that nums1 has enough space (size that is equal to m + n) to hold additional elements from nums2.

---

I ended up with coming up with this code:

```
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
  var nums = [];
  nums1.length = m;
  nums2.length = n;
  nums = nums.concat(nums1);
  console.log(nums);
  nums = nums.concat(nums2);
  console.log(nums);
  nums = nums.sort();
  console.log(nums);
  return nums;
}
```

This is what the 'run code' says:

> Your input
>
> [1,2,3,0,0,0]
>
> 3
>
> [2,5,6]
>
> 3
>
> stdout
>
> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
>
> [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6 ]
>
> [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6 ]
>
> Output:
>
> [1,2,3]
>
> Expected
>
> [1,2,2,3,5,6]

(an image version if the quotes weren't clear)

[image: an image version if the quotes weren't clear]

When I'm console.logging the array, the answer is correct but for some reason returning the array gives a completely different output

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: You return a *new* array `nums`. You should probably be returning `nums1`.

Comment: if console.log(nums) is giving the expected output but returned value of nums is different without changing anything, then you must be returning num1 instead of nums XD

Comment: @VLAZ but I'm concatenating the two arrays to nums, so returning nums1 would just return an array without the second array that I have to concatenate.

Comment: I'll try concatenating in nums1 instead

Comment: @KAI Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly - you should be *working with* `nums1` - the test seems to only be checking that, rather than the return value. When you make a new array, you're not changing `nums1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the hint here is that `nums1` is big enough to hold `n+m` values. So the way to solve this problem is to work backwards through both arrays, filling the empty space in `nums1` as you go. So for example, for the first iteration of the loop, you would compare `nums1[n-1]` and `nums2[m-1]` and put whichever is larger into `nums1[n+m-1]`. You then continue this for as long as you have values in either array, copying exclusively from the other if one runs out:

```js
const merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
  n--; m--;
  for (let i = m + n + 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    nums1[i] = (m < 0 || n >= 0 && nums2[n] > nums1[m]) ? nums2[n--] : nums1[m--];
  }
  return nums1;
}

console.log(merge([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], 3, [2, 5, 6], 3));
```

This code is `O(n)` (as compared to your sort which is `O(nlogn)`) and requires no additional space.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes complete sense and it's really useful